# After parsing table to string -> invert (parse string to table)

Tags: string, parsing, lua, lua-table

I've got that multidimensional table that I parse to a string (works fine).
Later in the runtime, I may have to parse it back (it contains configurations).

Is there any comfortable way to parse a string to a multidimensional table?

EXAMPLE:

```
table_xy = {}
table_xy.a = {  a= {}, b = 12, c = "sdf" , d = true , e = {}}
table_xy.b = { false,true,true,false}
table_xy.a.a = {lolbert, roflcopter}
table_xy.a.e = {4, table_xy.a.e}
```

print(string_from_table_xy) (after parsed) output:

```
{a={a={},c="sdf",b=12,e={4,{}},d=true},b={false,true,true,false}}
```

The highest depht is 7th tables away from the mothertable but this may change later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can load the string and then run it as a function like this:

```
local func = assert(load("return " .. string_from_table_xy))

local t = func()
```

In Lua 5.1, use `loadstring` instead of `load`.

Answer (score 1):

Oh dear, sorry for disturbing you.
The answer is simple as it could be.

```
loadstring(string_from_table)
```

Works pretty well. Sure, it's slow but i don't think one could do this with better performance while holding the comfort of this single line.